# Running Python3 on the ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine terminal without using "python3"

Tags: command-line, python, python3

I am trying to run a python program on the terminal directly without using the interpreter's name but I am getting error:

```
$ cat > scr.py
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
 
 print ("Hello World") ^Z [2]+  Stopped                 cat > scr.py
```

But when I try to execute the program:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ ./scr.py
bash: ./scr.py: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Text file busy
osboxes@osboxes:~$ chmod +x scr.py
osboxes@osboxes:~$ ./scr.py
bash: ./scr.py: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Text file busy
osboxes@osboxes:
```

But when I use the name "python3" explicitly, the program executes

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ cat scr.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print ("Hello World")
osboxes@osboxes:~$ python3 scr.py
Hello World
osboxes@osboxes:~$
```

Somebody please guide me how to solve this problem.

Zulfi.

Comment: It looks you put the file in the background, you need to kill it, `fg 2` then `ctrl+c`... you terminate cat with `ctrl+d` [1](https://superuser.com/a/169055)